# Simple assembly h8s program

Tags: assembly

I have to make a simple assembly h8s program. It should take input form keyboard:0 or 00 or 000 or 0000 ... 00000000. Then it should add 1 and then print the result till 111111111. And digits should be flipped like this form 0000 + 1 = 0001 to 1000 then 0100 then 1100 ... 1111. so far I have this:

```
           .h8300s

           .equ syscall,0x1FF00               ; simulated IO area
           .equ PUTS,0x0114                   ; kod PUTS
           .equ GETS,0x0113                   ; kod GETS

; ------ datovy segment ----------------------------

            .data
txt1:           .asciz "Zadejte velikost čísla (0-00000000):\n"  ;vypisovany text ukonceny \n
buffer:         .space 100                         ; vstupni buffer

            .align 2                           ; zarovnani adresy
par1:           .long txt1                         ; parametricky blok 1
par2:           .long buffer                       ; parametricky blok 2


            .align 1                           ; zarovnani adresy
            .space 100                         ; stack
stck:                                        ; konec stacku + 1

; ------ kodovy segment ----------------------------

           .text
           .global _start

_start:         mov.l #stck,ER7

            mov.w #PUTS,R0                     ; 24bitovy PUTS
            mov.l #par1,ER1                    ; adr. param. bloku do ER1
            jsr @syscall

           mov.w #GETS,R0                     ; 24bitovy GETS
           mov.l #par2,ER1                    ; adr. param. bloku do ER1
           jsr @syscall

           mov.w #PUTS,R0                     ; 24bitovy PUTS
           mov.l #par2,ER1                    ; adr. param. bloku do ER1
            jsr @syscall

lab1:     jmp @lab1                          ; konec vypoctu

           .end
```

So the only thing it is doing is that it takes what I write into console and then print it.Any ideas how should the program look like ?